# Email extraction from csv using regex

Tags: regex, email-validation

I have the following regex:

`/(.+?)((?:(?:[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(?:\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(?:".+"))@(?:(?:\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})))/gi`

Used to extract email address and name from the following different formats and avoid duplicates,

1. `"FName LName" <fname.lname@gmail.com>, "Eg Name" <egname@gmail.com>,
   Closed Call<close_call@gmail.co.um>`
2. `toys@urs.com`
3. `serima<serima@google.com>`
4. `One <one@one.com>;Two <two@two.com>; "New <new@new.com>"`

Have couple of problems with it:

- On **test case #2** `t` gets trimmed, getting only `oys@urs.com`, this happens only on the first email address.
- Second capturing group returns Name (if present along with a < if present) and then had to strip out the `<` separately

Any way to extract the above as follows, in much more elegant/efficient way

1. `[{'name':'FName LName', 'email':'fname.lname@gmail.com'},
   {'name':'Eg Name', 'email':'egname@gmail.com'},
   {'name':'Closed Call', 'email':'close_call@gmail.co.um'}]`
2. `[{'name':'', 'email':'toys@urs.com'}]`
3. `[{'name':'serima', 'email':'serima@google.com'}]`
4. `[{'name':'One', 'email':'one@one.com'},
   {'name':'Two', 'email':'two@two.com'},
   {'name':'New', 'email':'new@new.com'}]`

**Note:** Name may/maynot be enclosed with double quotes, there may/may not be space between the name and `<`

Comment: "Elegant" depends on what the implementation or end language you are applying it to is...

Comment: trying it in javascript,.. by elegant, trying to see if I can avoid the post processing (eg: strip the `<`) after regex'ing

Comment: I think you can fix problem #1 by inserting `[\n]*` immediately after the first capture group (e.g. `(.+?)[\n]*...`), or more greedy as you mentioned `(.*?)`. For issue #2 the `<` didn't show up in the matches when [I tried it](https://regex101.com/r/yYlMCJ/1).

Comment: thank you, got problem1 resolved, changing `/(.+?)` to `/(.*?)` worked as well. I do see the `<` in the [link](https://regex101.com/r/yYlMCJ/1)

Comment: I must be blind, which group is it showing in? All the group number two matches look clear of extra characters...

Comment: Oh you are not blind, I didn't mention in clearly :-) email group (group#2) is clean, but `<` is showing up in the Name group (group#1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem#1** solved by making the first capturing group a little more greedy,

`/(.*?)((?:(?:[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(?:\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(?:".+"))@(?:(?:\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,})))/gi`

**Problem#2** will save it for tonight's dream-time ;-)